# HW device via COM port, access individual pins

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

I'm currently working on a project which involves dealing with a HW device tailor-made for this purpose.

The device will serve the purpose of sending certain data via serial port (COM1, for instance). The data it is supposed to send doesn't matter that much.

I already have some knowledge regarding Windows serial port communication. CreateFile, WriteFile, and so on... BUT...

There is one "engine" on the device, which will send me the data when I ask it to, and in order to do so, I need to send there a signal (10101010) the rate of which will indicate the clock rate of that device "engine".

Here comes the explanation of how this device work. It gets a signal to send data through one pin. I'm supposed to send there 0 for start, 1 for end. Then, after this, it will watch some other pin for signal, sample it, and based on the frequency of ones and zeroes I send to it, it will start sending data via the thrid pin.

My questions are:

How to access individual pins of COM port?
How to manage the frequency and any delays I will need by myself?

I think that maybe I will have to do on this in kernel more by use of device drivers which will have to be developed.

Comment: Too vague, pins have names.  Presumably you tinker with the modem control signal, it is the kind of scheme to auto-detect the baudrate.  Which does give you only one setting that matters, the parity, number of data bits, number of stop bits and handshaking matter as well.  Talk to an engineer at the company that created the hardware, you'll get an informed answer instead of a guess.

Comment: This is a home project I work on together with my teacher. He created the hardware, and I'm in the role of software developer for that... 

I have all the information I need. 

I searched all the data structures that specify the properties of the serial port communication in WinAPI and I cannot even specify somewhere that some particular pin should be used as "RTS (Request-to-Send) and so on. There is only standard.

Simply the device won't send me the data unless I tell it at what frequency I want it to stream the bits.

Comment: Control pins like RTS with EscapeCommFunction().

Comment: I know about this function, it will definitely come in handy in the future, but how am I supposed to send one bit to RxD pin and right after that, read one bit from TxD? Because ReadFile function doesn't handle the "clocking" that device needs...

Comment: The Win32 API does not give you direct access to the individual pins.

Comment: And what does? Is there a need to develop some drivers or use assembly or what? This is the only problem I'm facing right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way. The COM port will send out the signal of alternating 1s and 0s if you just send a 0xAA byte.

Comment: This is interesting. But I somehow get the idea how it works, but how to set it up using WinAPI. That's the most difficult and yet unsolved part which drives me crazy. Anyway, thanks. ;)

Comment: What I am suggesting is a standard use of CreateFile, WriteFile APIs to send the serial character which happens to have alternating 1's and 0's. The same as sending any other data. If you don't know how to send serial data that's another question. But it's well covered in MSDN and here.

Comment: I know how to do it, and I already did it, but the problem is, that the device works like this:
I send one bit, it sends one bit to me.

WriteFile sends the whole buffer... At least one byte. 

And even if it was able to send one bit, wouldn't it be an overkill?